# Can you identify this seedpod (Malvaceae)?

Tags: species-identification, botany, seeds

I collected this seedpod from a plant I was pretty sure belongs to the mallow family (Malvaceae). Location = Central Europe. Unfortunately I lost my picture of the whole plant. Can you help me to identify the genus/species?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] additional detail into your question based on [the detailed tag info page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info). In particular, it could be helpful to have: 1) a size estimate of this fruit; 2) a description of the whole plant — ideally including the arrangement and positioning of the fruits/flowers, but even herb vs. bush would help; 3) more geographical specificity; and 4) some idea of the environment the flower was in (e.g.s: marsh, grassland, forest) — including other plants you could recognize, dryness, and elevation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Lavatera trimestris (flower became-fruit & dried & exposed and seeds are dispersed)

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion.